# verify sql injection through sqlmap

Tags: php, mysql, security, penetration-testing, sqlmap

I have a small application, there is one field in which I can write a number and submit it, the page request goes to server and I get a response or no response (as per the argument)

Now I checked the field for sql injection and got that it is injectable which is fine for me since I am in testing mode.

[image]

This is the result, Now how I can verify that these field was actually injectable, I tried to copied the payload in the field and submitting it, but it didnt worked.

The query that takes the argument is like this

```
$q = " select * from users where id = $_REQUEST['cnic']";

// REST OF CODE FOR ITERATING QUERY
```

Comment: You really need to post the weak code that this vulnerability has uncovered. It's impossible to know how to reproduce this since you haven't given enough content.

Comment: Yeah, that is **dangerously** bad code, the [archetypical injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/), so it's good the scanner found it. When testing injection bugs you will have to properly URI encode your parameters. In this case, `page.php?id=PAYLOAD` where `PAYLOAD` is the injection payload properly encoded.

Comment: Since the sql injection known by the community for 15 years, at least. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721786/how-does-sql-injection-work-and-how-do-i-protect-against-it you will find a very good explanation over here. Also you will find very detailed demonstration page  http://www.codebashing.com/sql_demo here.

Comment: The second one should have output something different on your page.

Comment: I doubt that this is the actual code. You would get a syntax error for single `'` in your injected data that is missing its counterpart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the sqlmap used a *AND/OR time based time-based blind* injection you need to look **how long** did it take to perform the query.

If you submit value "`111' AND (SELECT * FROM (SELECT...`" it will take 5 seconds or more (because of the `SLEEP(5)` inside which gets executed).

See the sqlmap documentation, I am sure they describe that more deeply here.